# PyTorch RetinaNet train model inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, object-detection

I have `model = torchvision.models.detection.retinanet_resnet50_fpn_v2(progress=True)` and would like to train it on custom data. To get the loss, I have to exececute

```py
classification_loss, regression_loss = model(images, targets)
```

I have create a batch tensor for `images`, but for the life of me, cannot find how I am supposed to format `targets` for object detection... Each target has a bounding box and a class label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this official tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

In general , `targets` is a `list` of `dict`, for e.g

```
targets = [
    {
        "boxes": torch.as_tensor([[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]], dtype=torch.float32),
        "labels": torch.as_tensor([1,], dtype=torch.int64)
    }
]
```

Comment: What if I want to one-hot encode the labels? Or do I pass in an integer (e.g. the index in a list of labels) and then PyTorch converts to one-hot encoding under the hood?

Comment: @HarryStuart You don't need to use one-hot encoding yourself. `labels` is supposed to be a list of integer, and torchvision will do the other things for you. You can check the source code of how torchvision computes classification loss: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/detection/retinanet.py#L170

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted you answer. By any chance, do you also know how to input an image with no targets? Objects are sparse in my dataset so there will be many images with no targets.

Comment: @HarryStuart Look at this PR: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/1911, it said how to format the target for negative sample